# Magento: Display # of pages in category list page

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display the # of pages on the category list page. 
Something like this:

```
<?= Mage::getSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCollection()->getSize()->getLastPageNum(); ?>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Magento uses this:

```
$this->getCollection()->getLastPageNumber();
```